# make a string available and modifiable to all classes in java

Tags: java, string

I have a string and i want to make it available to all classes. every class can modify the string and the modification will remain with the string when i use the string again. i have 3 action listeners and i want to modify the string by every action listeners and to keep the changes. i want to write the modified string into a file and this is done in the main method. what should i do to make the string available to classes and to retain the modifications done by the classes?
i have tried this-

```
public class BasicGuiOnlyText {    
  static String outputHtml="";  
  //Rest code of the class }   
  mnuItemNew.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {    
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {    
    outputHtml+="<html>";  
  }  
}  
public static void main(String args[]){  
  BasicGuiOnlyText gui = new BasicGuiOnlyText();  
  OutputStream htmlfile= new FileOutputStream(new File("test.html"));//For the creation of HTML file  
  PrintStream printhtml = new PrintStream(htmlfile);
  printhtml.println(outputHtml);  
}
```

But this is not working. it is not available to the actionlistener class. if i use another string in the actionlistener class declaring it to be ststic, the string is not available to the main class.

Comment: Have you tried using `BasicGuiOnlyText.outputHtml` to access the string?

Comment: Try `public static String outputHtml="";`

Comment: Could you please provide some code that actually compiles? We don't know from *where* you want to access the `outputHtml` field. Is it all **one** class?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have a single classloader then

```
public Class Classname {
    public static STRING_NAME = String 
   ...
```

would be publicly available to any class as Classname.STRING_NAME

However to keep the string in a file you might be better to define a dedicated singleton class with methods to get and set the current value. Behind the put you would have your code to write out the value to a file, and behind the get value you would read the current value from the file.

If your application uses multiple threads then you may also need to synchronize the read/write operations.

something like

```
public class StringValue {
    private static StringValue instance = new StringValue();

    private StringValue() { 
       ... constructor 
    }

    public static StringValue getInstance() {
        return instance;
    }

    public synchronized void putValue(String newValue) {
        write to file...
    }

    public synchronized String getValue() {
        read the file ...
    }
}
```

If you have performance issues with the sychronization then you can go further with caching the current value.

The client code would be something like

```
String currentValue = StringValue.getInstance().getValue();

StringValue.getInstance().putValue("NewValue");
```

Comment: Your `instance` variable must be `static`.

Comment: Yes indeed, thanks for spotting this.  I have fixed the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Make the String public, and either use a static import to import it in your ActionListener, or import the class and use the reference `BasicGuiOnlyText.outputHtml`.

Remember that unless you specify the namespace of the class in which the variable lives, the JVM will not be able to resolve it.

Answer (score 0):

If its about just a String, i will prefer you to use something like a `Property file`, **where you can write into it and then read from it**. But Still if you want this into a Class instead of file...then do the below.

**1.** Create a `class` with a `public static String variable`.

**2.** Now Simply call this method from another classes using the Class name.

**Eg:**

```
public class Test{

    public static String s;


 }
```

**3.** And in the case of a **Multi-threaded** application, `synchronization` will be need.